# How to show image INSTANTLY after waiting for download

Tags: javascript

How can I use Javascript to instantly show an image after downloading?

I tried Image.onload but it shows the image little by little, presumably because the browser is downloading it and rendering at the same time.

How can I download the entire image, render the entire image and then INSTANTLY show the entire image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an image element and load if first, then show it

```
var image = new Image();
var src   = '/url/to/image.png';

image.onload = function() {

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;

    document.body.appendChild(img);

}

img.src = src;

if ( img.complete ) img.onload(); // old IE hack
```